# For compehesion in Java + one more condition

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to translate the code from Java to Scala:

```
class Item {
  public long lng;
  public String str;

  Item(long lng, String str) {
   this.lng = lng;
   this.str = str;
  }
}

Item[] items = getItems(...) //doesn't really matter
int maxCount = getMaxCount()
for(int i = 0; i < maxCount && i < items.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%d %s",items[i].lng, items[i].str));
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
class Item (val lng: Long, val str: String)
val items = Array(new Item(1, "11"), new Item(2, "22"))
val maxCount = getMaxCount
for {
      x <- items
      i <- 0 to maxCount
      if i < maxCount
  } println(x.lng.toString + " " + x.str)
```

Also, how can do that without `for {...}` using `filterWith` and `foreach` but **without** `var`?

It prints the string `maxCount*2` times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your values as class members; as you have it defined, they are constructor parameters. Prefix them with `val` to make them also class members:

```
class Item(val lng: Long, val str: String)
```

Also, in the last line the error indicates `s` and `l` are not a members of `x`. Their names are `str` and `lng`.

You don't need `i` at all as far as I can tell.

```
val maxCount: Int = ...
items.take(maxCount).foreach { x => println(s"${x.lng} ${x.str}") }
```

Comment: well, yes, I just didn't pay attention, but it prints them maxCount*2 times.

Comment: look at Java for loop and this is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Using `take` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150211/53013) by [WeaponsGrade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774411/weaponsgrade) is a nice solution, but won't help you if you truly need something related to the index. A straight-forward conversion would go like this:

```
for (i <- 0 until (maxCount max items.length)) {
```

or, for more complex conditions than a simple `max`, you could write it like this:

```
for (i <- 0 until items.length if i < maxCount) {
```

This is not the same thing as the Java for loop -- the only way to accomplish exactly what Java does is using recursion or while loops.

Now, there are alternative ways of writing this. First, instead of `0 until items.length` you could write `items.indices`, for any Scala collection.

Next, if you want both the item and its index at the same time, you could use this:

```
for ((x, i) <- items.zipWithIndex if i < maxCount) {
```

Using `filterWith`, you could write this:

```
items.indices.filterWith(i => i < maxCount).foreach { i => 
  println(s"${items(i).lng} ${items(i).str}")
}
```

Or pretty much any of the other alternatives. For instance, the `zipWithIndex` version becomes:

```
items.zipWithIndex.filterWith { 
  case (x, i) => i < maxCount 
}.foreach {
  case (x, i) => println(s"${x.lng} ${x.str}")
}
```